# ConnectionPoolManager for RedisNativeClient

Tags: redis

Is there a Connection Pool Manager available for RedisNativeClient? We are doing byte level operations and use **RedisNativeClient** instead of the **RedisClient**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I implemented. RedisClient inherits RedisNativeClient so using PooledRedisClientManager and then casting the connection to RedisNativeClient works fine. It holds the same TCP socket. 
P.S. I am using Dependency Injection so I keep the lifestyle of this helper class singleton.

```
//Lifestyle is singleton
public class RedisHelper:IRedisHelper
{
    private readonly PooledRedisClientManager _poolManager;

    public RedisHelper()
    {
        _poolManager = new PooledRedisClientManager("localhost:6379"); 
    }

    public void RedisSingleSet(string redisKey, byte[] redisValues)
    {
        using (var client = (RedisNativeClient)_poolManager.GetClient())
        {
            client.Set(redisKey, redisValues);
        }
    } 
}
```